# Error when Customizing Newform.aspx for Discussion Board ('A Folder with the name {0} already exists)

Tags: 2007

On WSS 3.o I have created an out-of the box Discussion Board called 'dd'. I need to Cusomize the NewForm.aspx.  As noted in numerous online articles I deleted the existing ListFormWebpart and inserted a new DataFormWebpart based on the discussion Booard. I didnt Modify the DataFormWebpart  in any way.

I save  the Newform.aspx, browse to the Discussion Board and create an Item with Subject 'Test'. All is good. But when I go to create a second Item With A subject of 'Test" I get an error saying  'A Folder with the name Lists/dd/Test already exists.

If I use the DataFormWebpart  I am allowed to create discussions with the same name , but if I switch to A DataFormWebpart  I am not.

Is this a known issue? Are there any work-arounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me here that you have your list new item page linking to the new folder page, so when you try creating a item its actually creating a folder (which is another item based on the folder content type).

To check this

- Open SharePoint Designer
- right click on your list and select properties
- In the List Properties dialog box, click the Supporting Files tab.
- Ensure that the content type its set to item and not folder for your new form.

Hope this helps

Renzo